# Append dictionary to dictionary as nested

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

```
for iteration, i_parameter in enumerate(list_of_things):

   # Call Function_a()
   dict_DFResults = Function_a(i_parameter, matrix)
```

The program iterates over *list_of_things* with 4 items in it.
Function_a returns a dictionary with 3 DataFrames {0: DataFrame, 1:DataFrame, 2:DataFrame}.
I'd like to append the returning dictionary from the function for each iteration to a new nested dictionary (*dict_things*), finally looking like this:
{0: {0: DF, 1: DF, 2: DF}, 1: {0: DF, 1: DF, 2: DF}, 2: {0: DF, 1: DF, 2: DF}, 3: {0: DF, 1: DF, 2: DF}}

I tried it with...

```
dict_things = dict_DFResults.copy()
dict_things.update()
```

...but all i tried didn't work properly.

Comment: If your indexes are numbers starting from 0, why don't you use list?

Comment: new_list.append(dict_DFResults.copy()) worked, but i'd like to try it with dicts

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, i.e. the elements are not in specific order. As you want your indexes to be numbers, lists will be more robust and efficient as that's exactly what they are made for. Also, what I mean is ```list_variable.append(Function_a(i_parameter, matrix))```

Comment: Good hint! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`.update` is designed to be used with iterable feed. One of possible ways is providing `dict`, then value of keys in `dict_things` would be updated to corresponding values in provided `dict`. That is you might do:

```
dict_things = {}
for iteration, i_parameter in enumerate(list_of_things):
   dict_things.update({iteration: Function_a(i_parameter, matrix)})
```

Above example is just for showing how `dict.update` can be used - this task might be done using dict-comprehension resulting in more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_things = {}
for iteration, i_parameter in enumerate(list_of_things):
   dict_things[iteration] = Function_a(i_parameter, matrix)
```

or using a dict comprehension:

```
dict_things = { iteration: Function_a(i_parameter, matrix) for iteration, i_parameter in enumerate(list_of_things) }
```